# Why does the timer (profiler) in Symfony Debug Toolbar exceed 100% time?

Tags: php, symfony1, profiling, symfony-1.4

I use Symfony (v1.4) debug toolbar a lot for troubleshooting and optimizing things.  One part of it continues to puzzle me and I haven't found a description anywhere online.

The Timers section includes a % time column which seems horribly inaccurate.  Adding the things there nearly always results in a total that is way over 100%.  Once I had a result that was about 500%.  Is this just a bug or is it a percentage of something other than it seems to imply?  Thanks.

Here's a screenshot of a typical result for me:

[image: Screenshot of Timer output]

edit: Also, I have seen some results where adding all the time(%) column is significantly LESS than 100%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd guess that some partials include other partials' execution times.

i.e. `_list_td_tabular` and `list_th_tabular` are both part of `_list`'s execution.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought of that too, and in the screenshot I gave, that may be the answer.  I have to look for a better (actually worse) example because I saw some before where that didn't seem to explain it.

Comment: I accepted your answer because I currently can't find one of those examples that defies your explanation.  Since I've been running the development (trunk) version of Symfony it's possible that it was a transient problem with an earlier release.